# .toFixed not for .0*

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I have a few values:

```
var one = 1.0000
var two = 1.1000
var three = 1.1200
var four = 1.1230
```

and function:

```
function tofixed(val)
{
   return val.toFixed(2);
}
```

this return:

```
1.00
1.10
1.12
1.12
```

[LIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/y5nEu/)

I want maximum size after dot - 2, but only if numbers after for != 0.
So i would like receive:

```
1
1.1
1.12
1.12
```

How can i make it?

Comment: +val.toFixed(2); gives you a real Number, chopped.

Comment: Do you know the semantic difference between `1.2` and `1.200`? The first one has a precision of 1 fraction digit and can be a rounded value of e.g. `1.23` or `1.18`. The second one has a precision of 3 fraction digits.

Answer (score 120):

`.toFixed(x)` returns a string. Just parse it as a float again:

```
return parseFloat(val.toFixed(2));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/y5nEu/1/

Comment: Exactly working, Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Assuming you want *String* outputs

```
function myFixed(x, d) {
    if (!d) return x.toFixed(d); // don't go wrong if no decimal
    return x.toFixed(d).replace(/\.?0+$/, '');
}
myFixed(1.0000, 2); // "1"
myFixed(1.1000, 2); // "1.1"
myFixed(1.1200, 2); // "1.12"
myFixed(1.1230, 2); // "1.12"
```

Comment: @Doorknob can you provide an example where this does this not work?

Comment: why make the dot optional?

Comment: @Doorknob did you try it? That won't happen because `1200..toFixed(2)` is `"1200.00"` so the RegExp won't go beyond the `.`, cutting just the `.00` and leaving `1200`.

Comment: `myFixed(1e30,2)` returns `"1e+3"` instead of the correct `"1e+30"`.

Comment: @Wiimm yes, situations where `.toFixed` returns scientific notation aren't handled by this answer, you can add a string check for an `e` in those cases if you wish to simply pass them through

Answer (score 12):

The "correct" way to do it is as follows:

```
return Math.round(num*100)/100;
```

If you want to truncate it to two decimal places (ie. 1.238 goes to 1.23 instead of 1.24), use `floor` instead of `round`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
parseFloat((2199.004).toFixed(2)) // 2199
```